# iOS - pushViewController without sliding Background Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Messing around with pushViewcontroller due to one of the awkward requirement :/

So there is a rootViewcontroller with 1 Background Image and UITableView with custom cells and there is a detailViewController with similar backgruound image with different views.

Requirement is:

On tap of UITableViewCell... the whole navigation animation should not affect the background image. Background Image should stay as it is and all other view should slide.

How I can slide only UITableView and display detail screen without changing background image ?

There is one possible solution is just add 2 child view controller and apply slide animation on both child. But in that case I have to keep on removing the child. I can't remove child because on tap of custom bottom back button I have to display the 1st screen instantly.

Any other possible solution or improvement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your `UINavigationController` in a custom view controller that contains the background image. Then make sure your content view, as well as the pushed controller's views have a clear background.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, would you mind sharing more specific steps to do this?