# Push navigationController while persisting a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue, pushviewcontroller

I am using a navigation controller to push from vc1 to vc2. I have a mapview in vc1 which I want to also have replicated in vc2, so that it appears that essentially only a new navigation bar animated into view and the mapview didn't ever move during the transition to vc2.

I've tried setting vc2.mapview = self.mapview in vc1 prepareForSegue, but I didn't like the transition. I've tried custom modal segues too to overlay the mapview with a clear background in vc2, but then the map won't detect touches.

This is similar to the problem Tariq had here ([iOS - pushViewController without sliding Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125241/ios-pushviewcontroller-without-sliding-background-image)), but for me I need to be able to still interact with the mapview in vc2.

Any suggestions at all are welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to find a way to split window in 2 view controllers. One on top and one bottom.
The top one should have navigation controller while the bottom one only the map.
Make some links between them and you're done.

Or you can use `UITabBarController`

Comment: Thanks @Merla Dan, not sure I quite understand though. Are you saying I should have the navigation controller sit on top of a view controller than contains the mapview and then just do a push segue on that top navController?

Comment: No.. As root of app you have a window. In window you put 2 viewcontrollers. Those viewcontrollers should be visible in the same screen. One should be with navigation controller and the other with the map. When you segue.. it will segue only the one with navController and the map stays where you want

Comment: Like Master-Detail project on iPad

Comment: hi I played around with your suggestion and I think I'm on the right lines now... I have a uiview embedded in a uinavigation controller and also within that uiview I have a container view which is where I'd put the map. Then I'd work on only segueing the navigationcontroller, not the container view?